# cufon headlines not getting rendered on ajax based wordpress-pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, pagination, cufon

i used the following ajax-javascript for my wordpress-pagination within my header.php (i didnt want to have the whole site reloaded -> just the DIV wrapping the pagination):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#PaginationExample a').live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            jQuery('#contentinner').html('Loading...');
            jQuery('#contentinner').load(link + ' #main_rechts');

        });

    });
</script>
```

i'm also using the cufón-script to render my h1-headlines in a "real" fonttype. the problem is: everything will be rendered fine in the first place but when i click on the pagination (so that the ajax-content will be activated) the h1-fontrendering breaks and the original webfont will be shown (only within that "#contentinner"-DIV!

i've searched the web and all pages give the solution by adding

```
"$('selector').load('/feed', Cufon.refresh);" to my code...
```

but where do i add this? i tried this to the javascript in my header.php like this:

```
jQuery('#contentinner').load(link+' #main_rechts', Cufon.refresh);
```

..but its not working. the h1-headlines will not be rendered after clicking that ajax-event... please, help.. i searched for hours...

thanks,
Zayarb

Comment: don't forget the () after Cufon.refresh. It should be `Cufon.refresh()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('#contentinner').load(link+' #main_rechts', function(){ Cufon.refresh() });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#contentinner').load(link+' #main_rechts', function() {
  Cufon.refresh();
});
```

Would call cufon.refresh when the load is complete (even if it fails).

You sure you don't need to call refresh on the added elements?

```
Cufon.refresh('h1');
```